# What does "closed" mean in Heine Borel for $C^0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, definition, compactness, equicontinuity

Heine Borel for $C^0$:

> A set $\mathcal{E} \subseteq C^0([a,b], \mathbb{R})$ is compact if it is
>   closed, bounded and equicontinuous.

I don't really understand what closed mean in the definition.

> Consider the $f_n(x) = \sin(x+n),x \in [0,1]$, and let $\mathcal{E} = \{f_n(x)\} $ I want to show
>   that this set is compact

1. We know $\mathcal{E}$  is bounded since $\sin(x+n)$ is bounded
2. We know $\mathcal{E}$ is equicontinuous, since $\sin(x+n)$ is bounded and its derivative $\cos(x+n)$ is also bounded, by intermediate value theorem, $\mathcal{E}$ is equicontinuous
3. Closed.....?

What does it mean by $\{\sin(x+n)\}$ to be closed? Can someone provide an example of a set $\{f_n\}$ that is closed and not closed?

Comment: This theorem is usually called Arzéla-Ascoli Theorem.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Yes but the statement of Heine Borel is that a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact if it is closed and bounded. Therefore this statement is generalized or actually better Heine Borel for $C^0$. Or do you mean that Arzela Ascoli is equivalent to Heine Borel for $C^0$? I know nothing about that

Comment: I just wanted to say that you will find this theorem in the literature under this name - not under "Generalized Heine-Borel".

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I agree I made a mistake, the generalized Heine Borel is the one that says a set in a metric space  $(M,d)$ is compact if it is closed and totally bounded.

Comment: The set $\mathcal E$ isn't clear because you don't say what values $n$ can have.  If it is $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$, for example, then it isn't closed, But it it were $\{f_n:n\in\mathbb R\}$, then it would be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, the Arzela-Ascoli theorem usually says something to the effect of "if $E$ is bounded (in the uniform metric) and equicontinuous, then $E$ is precompact". Precompact means "has compact closure". A closed, precompact set is compact and vice versa. I just mention this because this is what you are more likely to find if you go searching in books or online.

That aside, closed here means the same as it does in any topological space. However, it is probably easier to think about it in terms of metric spaces: $E$ is closed if any sequence in $E$ which converges in the uniform metric has its limit in $E$.

This matters to the theorem above because a set in a metric space which is not closed can't be compact. This is because you could have a sequence which is convergent to a point outside the set, and such a sequence can't have a convergent subsequence.

An example of a non-closed set in $C^0$ is $\{ f_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ where $f_n(x)=1/n$ (regardless of $x$). Here the limit is $f(x)=0$ (again regardless of $x$) but this is not in the set. Another non-closed set is any open ball, e.g. $\{ f : \| f \|_\infty < 1 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a singleton set and as such is closed in our normed space $C_0([a,b],\Bbb R)$. (Note that the space in question is a space of functions, i.e., when we refer to a *point* of this space we really mean a continuous function).

A more general subset $S$ of our space is closed if its complement is open, that is for efery $f\notin S$ ther exists $r>0$ such that for all $g\in C^0([a,b],\Bbb R)$ with $d(f,g)<r$  we also have $g\notin S$. (Also recall that $d(f,g)=\|f-g\|_\infty=\max\{\,|f(x)-g(x)|\mid x\in[a,b]\,\}$.

Comment: Hi could you provide a set of functions that serves as an example of a not closed or open set?

Comment: The set is not a singleton set. It's a set of many numbers. And thus, it is not a set of functions which makes it not really useful for the above question. Maybe, the intention was to range over all $n$ (instead of all $x$).

Comment: @Lookbehindyou Take, e.g., $\{1/n : n\in\mathbb N\}$ of constant functions as a set which is neither open nor closed in $C[0,1]$,

Comment: the set as written makes no sense to me, perhaps the $x\in[0,1]$ should be $n\in\mathbb N$. I see the point that the "set is a singleton" but, as written, it is not even that (it just cannot be parsed to make sense of it).